# Finding $z$ for Complex Convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having an issue understanding how to go about solving a problem regarding complex sequences.  The problem is as follows:

> Find a $z$ for which the following sequence converges: $f_{n} (z) =e^{nz}$

My attempt thus far is:
$$f_{n} (z) = e^{nz} = e^{nx} \cdot (\cos(ny) + i\sin(ny))$$

Then I was planning to use the fact that both the real part and the complex part must converge if the sequence converges, so:

$$\text{Re}(f_{n}(z)) = e^{nx}\cos(ny)$$
$$\text{Im}(f_{n}(z)) = e^{nx}i\sin(ny)$$

But where do I go from here?

Comment: But when you set $z = x+iy$, you get $e^{nz} = e^{n(x + iy)} = e^{nx}\cdot e^{iny} = e^{nx}(\cos(ny) + i\sin(ny))$. *Hint*: For $x < 0$ you have an exponentially decreasing factor everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$.  Then, note that $f_n(z)=e^{nx}e^{iny}$.

The real and imaginary parts of the sequence $f_n(z)$ are given respectively by

$$\text{Re}(f_n(z))=e^{nx}\cos(ny)$$

and

$$\text{Im}(f_n(z))=e^{nx}\sin(ny)$$

Note that if $x< 0$, the exponential term $e^{nx}$ approaches zero as $n\to \infty$.  Since both the sine and cosine functions are bounded in absolute value by $1$, both real and imaginary parts of the sequence converge to zero for $x<0$.

If $x=0$ and $y=2\pi \ell$ for any integer $\ell$, then the sequence converges to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistake, I understand your logic and it makes perfect sense now!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: Was the omission of $x=0$, $y=2\pi k$ intentional?

Comment: @user5713492 Yes, I did omit that case and have added it upon edit.